# Windows Local Port disappearing after every restart

Tags: windows, networking, printer, network-printer, windows-server-2019

Since 1903 update both windows 10 and windows server are facing the issue that we can add a Local port but it disappears after every restart. The port apparently exists in registry but does not shows up in printer properties. This causes long delays in every software when print command is given.

My local port - \\192.168.1.15\EPSON

Reddit thread - https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/h78fcq/how_is_nobody_talking_about_local_printer_ports/

ANY workaround would be appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

From the Reddit thread you cited,
[How is nobody talking about local printer ports disappearing after print spooler is stopped or machine reboot? KB4556799, KB4560960](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/h78fcq/how_is_nobody_talking_about_local_printer_ports/):

> The printers that are set to a an IP port (not local port) do not seem to have the problem and we can set things this way.

This would require when creating the printer port to choose "standard TCP/IP port"
instead of a local port.

Comment: Sorry, but I have to add Local port. We have old printers in our office. So what we are basically doing is that connect those printer to some pc. Now the local port will send the command to that pc. The printer does not have any IP. So in this case, Standard TCP/IP Port can not be used.

Comment: The only other solution is also covered in the post, which is to remove the updates of KB4556799 and KB4560960 in reverse order and ban them, restarting after each removal. (At least until Microsoft comes up with a fix to the faulty fixes.) In the meantime, you may file a bug-report with Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

- First possibility is that the IP address is dynamic.  So, consider using a fixed IP address.
- Nowadays printers are really cheap (the cost is in the ink/cartridge).  So buy IP printers.
- Connect the printer to a desktop PC and share it on Windows
- If you cant afford to replace your printers then you can get printer to ethernet adaptor dongles.